# AWS EC2 - Public IPv4 address not working on a running EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to display a very basic node.js app on an ec2 instance. I have it running on local host just fine but when I try to launch it on an ec2, it displays this error: [image]

I know it has something to do with the ports, but I'm not sure what the issue is. Here is the very basic source code:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello! Yes!');
}).listen(8080);
```

and here is a screenshot of my security configurations in the AWS EC2 instance:

[image]

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly adding `http` in front of the URL: `http://<ec2-public-ip-address>`

Comment: Ohh, I know what the problem is. Your server is listing on port 8080, so the url should be `http://<ec2-public-ip-address>:8080`

Comment: I was putting port 8080 after, but I just realized my issue. Your first answer seemed to be correct. I was putting https instead of http! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was making changes in outbound rules. But actually, you have to write your port number & all other rules in **inbound rules**.